# How to copy part of text to another place in text with regular expressions and replace

Tags: texstudio, regular-expressions

I am trying to use the regular expression feature from TexStudio to replace text

```
1) \hyperref[code1]{some text (code1)}\index{};

2) \hyperref[code2]{some other text (code2)}\index{};
```

with

```
1) \hyperref[code1]{some text (code1)}\index{some text};

2) \hyperref[code2]{some other text (code2)}\index{some other text};
```

But I can't do it. So I was wondering if there’d be a code to help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match query

```
\\hyperref(.*){(.*)( \(.*\))}\\index{}
```

Replace query

```
\hyperref\1{\2\3}\index{\2}
```

[image]